# Mysql? Plesk Ec2 aws error 100% full xvda1

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, plesk

I am having a full disk problem using plesk on aws I don't know what may be consuming such space, I have almost nothing on the server

How do I see which files are consuming such space and which one can I delete? (avoiding any files from  system)

Result of df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            468M     0  468M   0% /dev
tmpfs            98M   11M   88M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1      9.7G  9.7G     0 100% /
tmpfs           490M     0  490M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M   16K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           490M     0  490M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/9289
/dev/loop1       97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9436
 /dev/loop2       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1566
/dev/loop3       29M   29M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/2012
tmpfs            98M     0   98M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Error displayed by plesk

```
DB query failed: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1021 Disk full (/tmp/#sql_448_0.MAI); waiting for 
someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space left on device"), query was: DESCRIBE `sessions`

Type    Plesk\Exception\Database
Message DB query failed: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1021 Disk full (/tmp/#sql_448_0.MAI); 
waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space left on device"), query was: DESCRIBE `    sessions`
File    Mysql.php
Line    60
```

Thanks

```
15M     bin
102M    boot
0       dev
13M     etc
44K     home
0       initrd.img
0       initrd.img.old
230M    lib
4.0K    lib64
16K     lost+found
4.0K    media
4.0K    mnt
1.1G    opt
1.1G    pleskswap
du: cannot access 'proc/21705/task/21705/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/21705/task/21705/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/21705/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/21705/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0       proc
60K     root
832K    run
15M     sbin
790M    snap
4.0K    srv
0       sys
64K     tmp
2.0G    usr
5.3G    var
0       vmlinuz
0       vmlinuz.old
```

var/log is 1.1G
var/lib is 4.2G

var/lib/psa is 3.4G
var/lib/psa/dumps is 3.4G

dumps contains a lot files like
backup_ext_advisor_2005xxxxx.tgz

Safe to remove entire folder?
Any way to avoid creation of these files?

Comment: Run `du -sh *` in the root of the server via `cd /` then following the trail up each level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `du -sh *` in the root of the server via `cd /` then following the trail up each level.

Alternatively suggestions for places to check first are:

- `/home` for any users
- `/var/log` - Check for any large logs files that have possibly not been rotated or grown large too quickly.
- `/opt` - Any applications installed on disk that are using disk space

Comment: Heres the suggestion: https://talk.plesk.com/threads/plesk-backup-var-lib-psa-dumps-full.94289/. Basically delete enough to get your OS free and then migrate the other off your disk to external storage, perhaps S3?